# What is a precise formulation of how people select one association as a high-probability indicator?

Tags: induction, reason, cognitive-sciences

Consider there are 2 problems for some given belief.

1. It is claimed that a present state of affairs *strongly* implies or determines, or makes highly probable, some future state of affairs - some projection, extension, or continuation of the thing - when there is no “**intrinsically logical**” connection between the two.
2. They implicitly seem to assume the prominent factor they are prefixated on is **exclusive**. It is strongly determining, and this is *sufficient* to draw a conclusion (as opposed to just, a necessary factor in something happening, but not sufficient - there ignore the possibility of alternatives).

Here’s what I mean.

1. The idea that it is likely that AI will become super-intelligent within a few years and make the rational choice to exterminate or enslave humans (or something).
2. A milder example, a Tweet claiming that open source AI cannot match the capabilities of proprietary AI, because AI’s performance depends on the amount of training, which requires expensive training costs.

These are just examples for a common abstract principle that I am not sure I have seen fully formalized, but maybe it could be, perhaps using some kind of knowledge graph / ontology approach.

In the spirit of Daniel Kahneman, there may be no intrinsic connection between a computer that can write code and a “sentient”, “conscious” AI with private motives (for example, maybe there will be a hard thesis like Godel’s incompleteness theorem in coming years proving limitations on the cognitive capacities of the LLM architecture). I think Kahneman calls this the “framing effect”. It is when you go to a bank and decide your money will be safe there because the interior design was pleasant, or you think a person is more likely to be a librarian than a farmer when described as “quiet and bookish”. In the first case, there is no intrinsic connection (perhaps) between how nice a room is decorated and if the people at the bank are planning on lying to you or not (for example). In the second, (Kahneman writes), it is more likely overall that a given person is a farmer, because that profession is far more common, worldwide.

I feel like I never finished thinking about this, when I read it years ago.

On the one hand: what **truly** is the fallacy being committed, by a person, here? And is that really a fallacy? Conditional probability comes to mind, where “diagnostic factors”, and qualitative experience, may indeed have some relationship with updating the likelihood of something. On the *other* hand, if “qualitative resemblance” is so “wrong”… why do we think it has some kind of relationship, and what is the thing we are supposed to use, in its stead?

Basically, if you explore these ideas further, you might find it needs more development, and the antitheses have their own problems - it is not the case that qualitative perception is somehow to be unilaterally ignored and rejected (probably), and it is not known what “pure reason” even *is* - I saw a really good quote by Nelson Goodman once, I can’t remember what it is, but it was talking about how, we have constantly *discovered* “principles of reason”, almost empirically - through trial an error, when an assumption is overturned, or leads to contradiction (non-Euclidean geometry, quantum mechanics, relativity, Godel’s incompleteness theorem, new types of logic like type theories or set theory without the axiom of choice) - I think a big problem in Kahneman’s book is it constantly implies there’s a “rational” substitute for all the supposed fallacies, but nobody knows what that is, that’s the open philosophical field of things like epistemology.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goodman/
https://www.philosophy-science-humanities-controversies.com/listview-details.php?id=237793&a=t&first_name=Nelson&author=Goodman&concept=Causality
https://academic.oup.com/book/8020/chapter-abstract/153391364?redirectedFrom=fulltext

The only tiny heuristic I have been trying to develop in my daily life as an antidote to “false positives”, “false positive links”, this pernicious human tendency to be profoundly swayed by things like, “Hey look, clouds are gathering in the sky, it is likely to rain,” I call, **denialism**: to counter the (wrong) human tendency to constantly find it *likely* that some kinds of qualitative resemblance actually have logical credibility - enough to base your worldview and predictions on - you should universally deny all assertions around you, to remind yourself that anything that has no logical proven connection may just as well be the opposite, and you are being duped by a trivial connection in your mind between certain remembered states of affairs or past patterns.

Thus, you could insist, “as LLMs grow increasingly powerful, it becomes less and less likely that humanity will die from AI extinction.” Why? You can just assert it without needing a reason. But, once you open your mind to that alternative, the creative, narrative-generating part of the mind, drawing connections between things, can start to fill in those gaps quite well.

I just found an article that struck me as being a perfect example of this. In 2014, mathematical linguist Andras Kornai argued it would be likely an intelligent AGI would infer morality as a rational necessity - to preserve its own existence, amongst other things. Here we have a narrative of the exact opposite: *it is overwhelmingly likely - rationality and statistics and the continuation of this or that trend - guarantee that AI will develop perfect moral standards - better than that of any human.”

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0952813X.2014.895109

So, we have some related phenomena on the table:

1. **The intrinsic lack of a logical connection.** People can say, “X necessarily implies Y,” and you can say, “Why? What if X necessarily implied not Y? How can we settle this?”
2. **People think in terms of qualitative resemblances.**
3. **People assume a single salient factor is exclusive.** They do not think about how an anticipated phenomenon could be affected by a different factor than the one they are staking all their predictive credence on.

But none of these ideas are clear, well-developed, precise, or even certain, and if they are true, a full range of implications from confirming or refuting them does not seem to me to have been done.

For example:

1. If that is *not* “an intrinsic logical connection”, how do you know? How do you demonstrate that? And what *is* one like? How do you show the difference between an intrinsic logical connection and not one? Is there a decidable procedure to identify one, every time?
2. What is so bad or wrong about “qualitative resemblances”? Why would people be so inclined to incorrectly think a present state of affairs is *likely* to continue, if this is apparently in all cases not true? And furthermore, if we genuinely reject this type of “qualitative” thinking, have we adequately expelled it from our daily lives, at all? And what remains in its stead?

These open questions intrigue me a lot.

---

This is another perfect example[*](https://twitter.com/mezaoptimizer/status/1667300224656715776?s=46):

> One [bad] thing that’s gonna make AGI safety difficult—once the model
> is sufficiently self-aware, it’ll know when it’s in training vs
> testing vs deployment

It is common to express reasons why you think something is not true, ie, counterexamples, counterarguments, counterscenarios (“How do you know it’s gonna become ‘self-aware’? As far as I can tell an LLM is literally Google Translate, it’s just random text streams, it has 1% of the characteristics of human consciousness, “being in the world”, and various distinct cognitive capabilities the architecture running it simply cannot emulate, the system itself doesn’t have that property.”) But that doesn’t get at the point to me - seeking a *categorical* argument, an argument from *form*, not content. All that can be weakly said it, “Not necessarily.” It feels like it is missing a must more rigorous formulation of some kind.

I think it depends on semantic precision. That’s my current approach.